# connection problem when connecting a mysql database to a webservlet on a payara server

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, payara

I have a Payara 6.2023.7 server and deploy a Java project on intellij on this server. I want to access my MySQL database via this webservlet:

```
@WebServlet(name = "helloServlet", value = "/hello-servlet")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private String message;
    @Resource(lookup = "jdbc/mysql")//"java:global/my-pool")
    DataSource ds;
    public void init() {
        message = "Hello World!";
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        // Hello
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><body>");
        out.println("<h1>" + message + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body></html>");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
        String username = "new_user";
        String password = "Password123!";

        try (Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("Select * from persons"); ) {
            out.println("Executed MySQL statement and got " + stmt.execute());
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(HelloServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

I have a  [connection pool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JfDp.png)([connection pool details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQ8hB.png)) with an associated [jndi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MErBe.png) .

When I call my webservlet, I get this error:

> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
> at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.datastructure.RWLockDataStructure.addResource(RWLockDataStructure.java:108)
> at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.addResource(ConnectionPool.java:288)
> at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResourceAndAddToPool(ConnectionPool.java:1532)
> at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResources(ConnectionPool.java:957)
> at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.initPool(ConnectionPool.java:236)
> at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.internalGetResource(ConnectionPool.java:527)
> at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.getResource(ConnectionPool.java:388)
> at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResourceFromPool(PoolManagerImpl.java:244)
> at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResource(PoolManagerImpl.java:171)
> at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.getResource(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:360)
> at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:307)
> 34 more
> Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: Communications link failure

Where am I going wrong?  I tried reinstalling payara, mysql and creating a new project in intellij.